# ERROR - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net

```
  ds.Clear()
        connString = provider & datafile
        con.ConnectionString = connString
        con.Open()
        sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo WHERE ID = '" & UserbeingEdited & "'"
        ds.Clear()
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "EDITING")
        con.Close()
        Dim recordCount, x As Short
        recordCount = 0
        x = 0
        recordCount = ds.Tables("EDITING").Rows.Count
```

Im having a problem edititing a user in my database. this is the code for when the EditUser form loads. the the error occurs. Please help!

Comment: In SQL putting anything between single quotes transform it in a string. If the ID field is a numeric field then why do you pass a string for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo WHERE ID = " & UserbeingEdited
```

Please remove `"'"` and use above code.